# Rviz unstable rendering

Tags: rviz, urdf, ros-melodic, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am learning URDF creation and having arrived at the end of the R2D2 tutorial, I found Rviz unstable and "gittery" in how it's rendering my robot simulation.
I am using the Joint-State-Publisher GUI to publish data to the continueous and revolt joints but the movements are far from smooth and hindering proper testing.

[Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vfLAkCL0bSH3lBSc3xXCwIgxFOEqX1Kc/view?usp=sharing) to a short video showing the unhelpful behaviour I am trying to resolve.

UPDATE:

Thank you @gvdhoorn
You are correct!

The rosnode list output does show is a joint_state_publisher node and a joint_state_publisher_gui node.

[image: image description]

RQT-Graph output:
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365140/rviz-unstable-rendering/) by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2020-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's likely you have one instance of `joint_state_publisher` and another `joint_state_publisher_gui`.

Please verify with `rosnode list` and `rqt_graph`.

Even if this is not the cause in this case, what you show/describe is not a "rendering issue", but you're feeding RViz two streams of data (via the `robot_state_publisher`, which publishes TF based on the `JointState` msgs):

- one which tells it all joints are always at zero, and
- one which tells it, no `header_joint` is at `0.76`

it should be obvious those two will conflict.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2020-11-09**:
Thank you. I corrected my mistake according to your input and all is now well in the Rviz-nivser.